# appending a picture to div when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is have users input to be added to the string and the picture of google streetview append to the div called map

I tried two different codes but neither worked.

```
$("#search").click(function(){
var citySearch = $("#city").val();
var map = $("map");
var streetView = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location="+ citySearch + "";
map.append('<img src="'+ streetView +'">')

})
```

and also used this with the button being onclick myFunction and onsumbit myFunction

```
function myFunction(){
var citySearch = $("#city").val();
var map = $("map");
var streetView = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location="+ citySearch + "";
map.append('<img src="'+ streetView +'">')

}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="" id="city">
<button id="search" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

<div id="map">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is to render image inside div with id "map" then your jQuery selector needs to be `#map`, not `map`:

```
var map = $("#map");
```